# Redirect a subdirectory to the main domain in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the folowing structure:

```
www.example.com - DE version 
www.example.com/de - DE version 
www.example.com/en - EN version
```

I want to be like that:

```
www.example.com - DE version
www.example.com/de ---> Redirect 301 to www.site.com
www.example.com/en - EN version
```

That's my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried examples but no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: What "examples" have you tried?

Comment: Example codes from internet... sorry for my English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `example.com/de` to `example.com` (and all the URLs within) then you can do something like the following (after your current directives):

```
RewriteRule ^(?:de|de/(.*))$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `/de` or `/de/` or `/de/something` to the corresponding URL in the document root. It won't redirect `/desomething` (in case you have other files in the root that start "de").

The `?:` after the first parenthesis makes the group non-capturing.

To prevent `/de/` (trailing slash) from redirecting you could change the `*` (0 or more) to `+` (1 or more) in the regex. ie. `^(?:de|de/(.+))$`